How do I cite a book with many translators?
I have a book (Readings in Chinese Women's Philosophical and Feminist Thought). The main editor and translator is Ann Pang-White, but it also contains many readings reproduced from other pre-existing translations, all from different years and by different translators. It's a sort of sourcebook. There is a full list of these at the front. If I were to be citing a specific reading then I wouldn't have a problem, but at this stage I'm just citing the book in general and I don't know what to do.

Should I just leave the translators out? Maybe - the book itself and the introduction etc., technically aren't translated, just all of the
collected readings within).

Should I just write "Pang-White, ed. and
trans." as if she's the only one? (Also seems wrong?)

Should I list
all the translators? Definitely seems wrong, as you would usually list these more like chapter authors than book authors with
chapter-specific citations and we don't put all those names in our
citations of a general book!


For reference, I am using Chicago Notes-Bibliography, and this is what I have at the moment:

Pang-White, Ann A., ed. Readings in Chinese Women’s Philosophical and
Feminist Thought: From the Late 13th to Early 21st Century. London:
Bloomsbury Academic, 2023.


I do not use Chicago, and rarely reference translations, however the citation you have (copied below) seems appropriate, if all of Pang-White's translations are on the same tier as the others, as in, she wrote the introduction and also contributed translations.

Pang-White, Ann A., ed. Readings in Chinese Women’s Philosophical and Feminist Thought: From the Late 13th to Early 21st Century. London: Bloomsbury Academic, 2023.

If the introduction, etc. was also translated by Pang-White, it would make sense to write ed. and trans., as you have suggested.
